# How to show mongoose data in a specific date range?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to display the data in a table  in a specific date range on my page by choosing the date range in the inputs (From To):
[image]

the data I want to show are coming from the sub-schema. I have the following schema:
first schema: User, second schema Tracker and third schema Income, Subcontractor and Siteexpense.

I want to show the data from Income, Subcontractor and Siteexpense but I don't know how to do it. I have the following post route to get the date range bu don't know how to fix the get route accordingley:

```
app.post("/report", isLoggedIn, function(req,res){
User.findById(req.user.id, function(err, foundUser){
      if(err){
          console.log(err);
      }else{
            var startDate = req.body.startDate;
            var finishDate = req.body.finishDate;
            Income.find({startDate: {
                $gte: startDate,
                $lte: finishDate
            }
        }).exec(function(err, income) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                }else{
                    console.log(income);
                    console.log(finishDate);
                    res.render("report",{user:foundUser, income:income});

                }
        });
      }

 });
});
```

the current get route is as follows and shows all the data from all the dates:

```
app.get("/report", isLoggedIn, function(req,res){
User.findById(req.user.id).populate({path: 'trackers', model:'Tracker', populate:{path:'incomes', model:'Income'}})
.exec(function(err, foundUser){
      if(err){
          console.log(err);
      }else{

                  res.render("report",{user:foundUser});
            }
        });
});
```

anyone can help me to solve this. Thanks

Comment: you can use `$lte` and `$gte` for finding data in between data range

Comment: startDate: {
                $gte:  new Date(2018, 6, 14),
                $lte: new Date(2018, 6, 15)
            }

Try It.